# Spring boot: request scoped @service or custom spring holder?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to collect several objects I need to fill at the end of some method execution.

The collected objects are generated along an http request. At the end of controller endpoint execution, these ones are flushed to database.

So, I'm looking for a way to collect them.

1. Is there any Spring Holder to be able to add any kind of object.
2. What about to create a request scoped `@Service` ?

Comment: Your description is very vague, can you explain clearly what do you mean by "I need to collect several objects I need to fill at the end of some method execution.The collected objects are generated along an http request. At the end of controller endpoint execution, these ones are flushed to database."

Comment: A request scoped bean in which you store the relevant objects should do the trick.